# Error while trying to Create a Static Page in Zen Cart in windows

Tags: zen-cart

am currently learning zencart , i am trying to create a static page on my zencart template using the link provided in [justins zencart](http://lifefeed.net/zencart/static_page.php) , The problem is when i execute the page in ubuntu operating system with lamp server i am able to get the page with all the details , but when i try to execute the same page in windows7 operating system  with easyphp , i get the following error

```
trail(BREAD_CRUMBS_SEPARATOR); ?>
'; ?>
```

, any help regarding this will be grateful

The code  that shows the above error is

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"> <tr><td class="breadCrumb"> <?= $breadcrumb->trail(BREAD_CRUMBS_SEPARATOR); ?> </td></tr> <tr><td class="pageHeading" align="center"> <h1><?= HEADING_TITLE; ?></h1> </td></tr> <tr><td class="main"> <?= TEXT_INFORMATION; ?> </td></tr> <tr><td class="main"> <?= zen_back_link() . zen_image_button('button_back.gif', IMAGE_BUTTON_BACK) . '</a>'; ?> </td></tr> </table>
```

Comment: can you please share full page code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing that information output in the HTML, then it means your PHP file is damaged, or you've added a closing ?> tag someplace where it doesn't belong.  It shouldn't be outputting PHP code directly.